# Replace bookmark URL JavaScript

Tags: javascript, browser, bookmarks

Scenario:
A reporting tool run in our company has been upgraded to a newer version. It is being accessed by a URL in a browser: www.company.de/programm/v8/client/
The users were able to save browser bookmarks. I.e.: www.company.de/programm/v8/client/report1

The updated URL has changed (www.company.de/programm/new/v10/client/), thus letting all saved user-bookmarks resolve into nothingness.

My question: Is there a snippet for JS that either updates the URL string from "*v8/*" to  "*new/v10/*" or at least scans to existing bookmarks inside the users bookmarks and adds new ones with a new URL (leaving the previous ones untouched)?

Comment: Do  you want this to be apply in all browser types?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to redirect the old URL to the new one ?

Comment: @gogaz: Hi, there are about 100 potential reports to be redirected. Could be a solution, though I wouldnt know how to do this in IIS7... I cannot to this inside the reports because the reporting tool wouldn't allow this.

Comment: @Thusitha it's not neccessary. If I would tell the folks to use a certain browser (ecept IE 11) when executing the function they would have to obey :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually can't change your bookmarks using javascript.
The easiest way to do that is to change the bookmark file manually

The Chrome one for example is located here:

> C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Bookmarks

Comment: hi, Thank you for this approach. A little BAT-File could do the trick I suppose

Answer (score 2):

No. You can not access the browser bookmarks though a webpage or in a JavaScript file within a web page.

But,

1. You can create a browser extension with the extension api which will scan all the bookmarks in a browser and give access to update those with new URLs. But this will need to install a custom browser extension in the user's browser. Browser extension API supports Chrome, Firefox and Safari, Edge with some polyfills. Sorry about the IE support. Writing extensions for IE is a nightmare.

You can read more about the extension api in
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/bookmarks

2. Simply redirect you old URL to the new URL.
   Which means redirecting `www.company.de/programm/v8/client/report1 -->` `www.company.de/programm/new/v10/client/` through the same web server. Implementation is varying with the server you use. Just write a path matching rule.

Comment: in IIS: If the URL contains ~/v8/~ ...  could i then simply redirect all traffic to ~/v10/~.